# How to get user details from access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I downloaded this sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/User%20Owns%20Data/integrate-report-web-app/PBIWebApp

and I am able to get access token. Next, I saved this access token in my database for future use. Using this token stored in database I want to get user's profile but not sure how to do it.

```
public string GetAccessToken(string authorizationCode, string applicationID, string applicationSecret, string redirectUri)
        {
            //Redirect uri must match the redirect_uri used when requesting Authorization code.
            //Note: If you use a redirect back to Default, as in this sample, you need to add a forward slash
            //such as http://localhost:13526/

            // Get auth token from auth code       
            TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();

            //Values are hard-coded for sample purposes
            string authority = Settings.Default.AADAuthorityUri;
            AuthenticationContext AC = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TC);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationID, applicationSecret);

            //Set token from authentication result
            return AC.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                authorizationCode,
                new Uri(redirectUri), cc).AccessToken;
        }
```

I checked methods of AuthenticationContext class but it doesn't have any method like 'GetMe' or something.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL is only for authentication, it is not for calling APIs like the Microsoft Graph API.

You'll need to acquire a token for the `https://graph.microsoft.com` resource, and then call the endpoint for user information: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get.

There is also an SDK which can make the calls a bit easier: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I could use this access token with Graph API or do I need a different type of access token? It is very confusing.

Comment: Also, please let me know is there any way in ADAL to know if the token is valid or not(perhaps expired or may be somebody erroneously modified the token in DB)?

Comment: Hard to say, you can check what the token audience (intended target) with e.g. https://jwt.ms (it's the aud claim). ADAL handles token renewals very nicely for you if they expire as long as the token cache is implemented correctly. Validation is not for you though, that's the APIs job.

Comment: OK - juunas. Seems fair. Any idea how to save TokenCache to SQL server database? I think by default it maintains in memory.

Comment: Yeah, default is in-memory. You can see an example of an SQL token cache here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/DAL/EFADALTokenCache.cs

Comment: I posted another query as I ran into some trouble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501050/sqlserver-tokencache-issue please help as time permits. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [JWTSecurityToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken?view=azure-dotnet) in C#. Also, you can visit https://jwt.io/ to see its working.